# How to secure erase a Western Digital My Cloud Mirror (Gen 2)?

Tags: raid-1, secure-erase

Before transmitting a **Western My Cloud Mirror 6TB NAS storage in RAID 1** (2x 3 TB) from one customer (selling it) to another one (buying it), I need to **wipe the data**, whilst preserving intact the system features.

In the NAS, the drives were in RAID 1. 
I extracted them from their enclosure and connected them in SATA using.

Listing the drives with `fdisk -l` in Linux Parted Magic distro gives the output below. The volume with the data is obviously `dev/md1`.

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/md0: 2147 MB, 2147418112 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 524272 cylinders, total 4194176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 2996.3 GB, 2996296343552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 731517662 cylinders, total 5852141296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

So, my questions:

1. To wipe the data stored on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` drives, will it suffice to shred `dev/md1`?
2. After applying `shred`, will I have to reformat the "volumes" making dev/md1 RAID?
   I don't think so as the data area on each drive show as RAW, but I would like to be sure before wiping the drive.
3. After data deletion mentioned at points 1 and 2, will  the [40-seconds reset](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?h=p2&ID=13987&lang=en&p=910) suffice to restore the WD My Cloud Mirror to factory state and prevent the new user from accessing the data from a previous user?

If the data were synced with some remote account in the cloud, I want to make sure that the buyer cannot accidentally access the seller's files there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `shred` with one pass would be enough

   shred -v -n 1 /dev/sda
2. No need to reformat as `shred` will remove all data including its format and partition tables.
3. You can unmount the drive partitions by `umount /dev/sda1` or `umount /dev/sdb1`. Also removing it from `/etc/fstab`.